# How to explicitly declare type of a variable when creating that variable with New-Variable function?

Tags: powershell

How can I cast `myChar` in `New-Variable -Name myChar -Value "=" -Option ReadOnly` to type `[char]`, or (more generally) how can I specify type of a variable created with `New-Variable`?

Thanks

EDIT (credit goes to @veefu):

```
[char]$sampleVariable="A"
$sampleAttributes=(Get-Variable -Name sampleVariable).Attributes[0]
New-Variable -Name myVariable
(Get-Variable -Name myVariable).Attributes.Add($sampleAttributes)
$myVariable="ab" # GENERATES CONVERSION ERROR (WHICH HELPS A LOT)
$myVariable="a"  # DOES NOT GENERATE CONVERSION ERROR (EVERYTHING'S FINE)
```

EDIT (credit goes to @postanote):

```
[char]$anyCharacter="A"
# FOLLOWING LINE GENERATES CONVERSION ERROR (GOOD THING)
Set-Variable -Name anyCharacter -Value "ab" -Option ReadOnly
# FOLLOWING LINE DOES NOT GENERATE CONVERSION ERROR (GREAT)
Set-Variable -Name anyCharacter -Value "a" -Option ReadOnly
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pretty much impossible to do now in PowerShell so I've opened an issue [You should be able to set the type conversion attribute on a variable with New-Variable](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7566) to address this.

Answer (score 4):

The difference between a variable with and without a type specifier `[int32]` is in the variable attributes:

```
[int32] $var1 = 32
$var2 = 'a'

Get-Variable -Name 'var1' | fl *
Get-Variable -Name 'var2' | fl *
```

yields:

```
Name        : var1
Description :
Value       : 32
Visibility  : Public
Module      :
ModuleName  :
Options     : None
Attributes  : {System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute}

Name        : var2
Description :
Value       : a
Visibility  : Public
Module      :
ModuleName  :
Options     : None
Attributes  : {}
```

`New-Variable` doesn't support setting these attributes, so it isn't possible to make the equivalent of `[int32] $myVarname` using `New-Variable`

It is possible to use the .net `[psvariable]::new()` constructor to create a variable with these attributes. I could not figure out how to construct the Attributes from scratch to make the equivalent of `[int32]`, but was able to successfully copy attributes from another variable during construction:

```
[int32] $int32ConstrainedVar1 = 32
$var1Attributes = (Get-Variable -Name 'int32ConstrainedVar1').Attributes
$newConstrainedVar = [psvariable]::new('int32ConstrainedVar2', 33, 'None', $var1Attributes)
```

After this, trying to assign something that cannot be converted to `[int32]` fails, as expected:

```
$newConstrainedVar.Value = 'asdf'
```

yields:

```
Exception setting "Value": "Cannot convert value "asdf" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format.""
At line:1 char:1
+ $newConstrainedVar.Value = 'asdf'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting
```

Sorry for the sketchy details; this is a level of powershell internals that's new to me.

I'm interested in what your use case is; The only reason I can imagine you'd want to work at this low a level with powershell is if you're writing a runtime that translates from another language into powershell.

Comment: "I could not figure out how to construct the Attributes from scratch"
should work on that in the future, would be a useful thing to know

Comment: This attribute class is defined [internal sealed](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/11631e7412197f3f803ebbef95a3ddb174a387ec/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute.cs#L15). The [compiler](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/4ee1973d976d66078fcffc54208accab0ec9d8c9/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/parser/Compiler.cs#L1519) is the primary creator of Attributes. For now, compiling the text `[typename] $variableName` via `Invoke-Expression` is the only way to create conversion attributes; But maybe there is some .net magic I don't know.

Comment: Interestingly, `ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute`'s constructor takes an array of types. Internally, it is possible to define a PSVariable with multiple type conversions and the logic to attempt conversion them all seems to be in place. The compiler code, though, only ever initializes with a single type. Something like `[int32,string] $var` might have been under consideration at some point.

Answer (score 2):

There is not native way using the cmdlet alone to do this as per its specification:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-variable?view=powershell-6

```
[-Name] <String>
[[-Value] <Object>]
[-Description <String>]
[-Option <ScopedItemOptions>]
[-Visibility <SessionStateEntryVisibility>]
[-Force]
[-PassThru]
[-Scope <String>]
[-WhatIf]
[-Confirm]
[<CommonParameters>]
```

After thinking about this a bit, one could apply the datatype after the create or inline, this way... 
(might be a way for you, relative to your use case, but again...)

```
[char](New-Variable -Name myChar -Value "=")
$myChar
=
$myChar.GetType()
IsPublic IsSerial Name      BaseType
-------- -------- ----      --------
True     True     String    System.Object   

Remove-Variable -Name myChar

[int](New-Variable -Name myChar -Value 1)
0
$myChar
1
$myChar.GetType()
IsPublic IsSerial Name      BaseType
-------- -------- ----      --------
True     True     Int32     System.ValueType

Remove-Variable -Name myChar

[decimal](New-Variable -Name myChar -Value 10.00)
0
$myChar
10.00
$myChar.GetType()
IsPublic IsSerial Name      BaseType
-------- -------- ----      --------
True     True     Double    System.ValueType

Remove-Variable -Name myChar
```

Variable type

Usually when you create a variable you implicitly set the type by the value you use. Sometimes though you may want to explicitly set the variable type.

if you don’t give the variable a type you can do this:

```
PS> $x = 35
PS> $x
35
PS> $x = 'now a string'
PS> $x
now a string
```

If you give the variable an explicit type

```
PS> [int]$x = 35
PS> $x
35
PS> $x = 'now a string'
Cannot convert value "now a string" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
At line:1 char:1
+ $x = 'now a string'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : MetadataError: (:) [], ArgumentTransformationMetadataException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

The variable expects an integer or something that can be converted to an integer

```
PS> $x = '123'
PS> $x
123
```

***You can’t supply a type when you use New-Variable so if you need a read only or constant variable then create it as shown above then use Set-Variable to make it read only or constant.***

https://blogs.msmvps.com/richardsiddaway/2018/08/18/variable-type

So, this still comes back to my earlier statement...

> one could apply the datatype after the create …

Set-Variable just did not come to mind in my earlier post.

Comment: After `[char](New-Variable -Name myChar -Value "=")` myChar can be assigned a non-char value: `$myChar=[int32]8` and this changes the underlying type of the value. When `[char]` is applied, this assignment throws an exception.

Comment: But your example was for a read only, so any change to that would be denied by design. I left my example open so, I could remove it. Any what I provided was one approach. See my update for you with another. Again,  you still cannot set type using New-Variable alone. So, looking at workarounds is your only option.

Answer (score 1):

So it is possible, i found a way.

Make a string the standard way:

```
[string]$var1 = 1
$var1.GetType().name
```

Make a string with set-variable:

```
Set-Variable -Name var2 -Value (New-Object -TypeName System.String -ArgumentList "1")
$var2.GetType().name
```

It also works with other objects:

```
Set-Variable -Name var3 -Value (New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]')
```

Comment: For future reference, this is known as a [contrained variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/lang-spec/chapter-05?view=powershell-5.1#53-constrained-variables) in the spec.